# DB Query using Django mapping

Tags: python, django

I have two Model classes defined as below:

```
class Program(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user_limit = models.IntegerField()

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    program= models.ForeignKey(Program)
```

I need to query set of Program objects, where User-objects linked to that Program has not exceeded the user_limit.

Comment: I have a feeling the model is wrong for what you are looking to achieve

Comment: I think you are missing a field in the User model to compare against the "user_limit"

Comment: You need a linking table that links Program and User and contains user_limit

Answer (score 0):

You want all the programs that have less than user_limit users associated with it. For performance I'd recommend that you have a user_limit and user_count. Every time you associate a user with a program increment the count. That way you can do a more simple query with more performance.

`from django.db.models import F
Program.objects.filter(user_count__lte=F("user_limit"))`
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model

Comment: Your suggestion to add a user_count field will definitely reduce query time. I'll see if limitations allows me to do so.
Thanks! again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! everyone for your help. I spent some more time on it and came up with this Query:

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models import Count
Program.objects.annotate('user_count'=Count('user')).filter(user_limit__gte=F('user_count'))
```